# How to get all data of a profile

Tags: apex, soql

I want to get all data including Object permissions, field permissions, system permissions, Apex class access, visualforce page access of a profile, but not able to do that from soql query since profile has only boolean fields available on profile abject.

Comment: Can you highlight which permission are not part of those field? Also, Can you explain why you want to get everything?

Comment: I just came to know that to get any Object specific permissions like create, read, edit delete we have to query on "ObjectPermissions" object specifying the Parent and sobject fields.

Sample Query: [SELECT PermissionsCreate, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete, PermissionsViewAllRecords, PermissionsModifyAllRecords FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true AND SObjectType = '<sObjectName>' AND Parent.Profile.Name = '<ProfileName>']

I want all these data to build a profile comparison tool that shows the difference between permission of two profiles

Comment: But still i need to figure out how to get data for field permissions, system permissions, Apex class access, visualforce page access for a profile. Any suggestion is welcome:)